# Can I stop a failed compilation from clobbering aux etc?

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files, tools

I have a complicated document which takes a while to compile (even with chapters commented-out entirely) and typically needs 3 passes to get everything right.

If a typo creeps in and breaks the compilation, I have to recompile the whole damn thing three times to get back to where I was. I would like pdflatex to revert all intermediate files to their "last good state" in the event of an error, so that after the typo is fixed, I can proceed with an incremental compilation.

I could brute force a solution by `cp`-ing the entire directory tree, but that seems rather crude. Is there a better way to recover from errors using the given tools?

Comment: not tested ... this assumes that your chapters are in separate files and pulled in with `\include`.  you can then insert `\includeonly{...}` in your preamble and specify only the chapter where the job failed.  the .aux files before that point will have been recreated already, and the ones after that point will not yet have been touched.  then you can delete just the .aux file from the chapter that failed, leaving the others from their previous, presumably valid, state.  alternatively (since you suggest that you could cp an entire tree), you could cp just the .aux files to save them.

Comment: you don't need to copy the entire tree, just `.aux` (or `.toc`) or anything else. But not normally necessary a "typo" is rarely bad enough to stop a job completing, and if editing surely it doesn't matter if you need multiple runs,  it's only worth doing one run anyway.

Comment: When `\begin{document}` is processed, the main `.aux` file is opened for writing, so its previous incarnation is destroyed. On the other hand, you don't have to run LaTeX three times; maybe cross references will be out of synch, but it's not a problem during document preparation.

Comment: Depending on your system and which editor you use for LaTeX you could write a Makefile which does just that. If you use something like vim for editting the call of the makefile could be easy done, too.